# Why does Heroku report error code H12 Request timeout for 30-sec-long requests?

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework-2.1

We are working with Play application on Heroku. And we deal with consuming computations on the server side, which require more than 30s on request. On the locale machine all work fine. But on heroku we always get an error code H12 ([Request timeout](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h12-request-timeout)).

Are there any hacks for this problem in the case of play and scala (are used 2.1 versions)?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku does not support long lived requests. The best way to get around this is to give your client a callback url and have them pull for the response. There is a library in play that helps you do sort of thing and wraps it up nicely for you. It is called comet.

Here is an example of it's use

```
public static Result index() {
  // Prepare a chunked text stream
  Chunks<String> chunks = new StringChunks() {

    // Called when the stream is ready
    public void onReady(Chunks.Out<String> out) {
      //Start your long running process here
      out.write("<script>console.log('kiki')</script>");
      out.write("<script>console.log('foo')</script>");
      out.write("<script>console.log('bar')</script>");
      out.close();
    }

  }

  response().setContentType("text/html");

  ok(chunks);
}
```

More information on asyn http programming with play can be found here:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaComet

Comment: Could you make a small example for this, if it's not difficult.

Comment: Thanks, Eric! But I found another way like splitting a long request into many short ones.